# How do I move to the newly created method generated by Eclipse's "Add unimplemented methods"-Quick Fix?

Tags: eclipse

After generating a default function skeleton using Eclipse's **Quick Fix** function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> Windows, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> OS X) how do I move to it?

The content of the function-skeleton is rarely sufficient, and this remains one of the few situations where I have to reach for the rat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to navigate using a navigator view, preferably one like the Package Explorer which shows methods.

If you're good about getting rid of TODO comments as you work through the code you can also navigate to lines marked with TODO (unimplemented methods are usually added with a TODO comment).  Those lines are annotated just to the left of the text area.

Comment: Is there a known way to navigate to the next/previous `TODO` in the current file? I've been unsuccessful in googling as well as browsing the built-in `Preferences`>`Keys` list for anything relevant.

Comment: No way that I know of, other than to find it's annotation to the left of the text area and then click on that annotation.  I suppose you could do a search of some sort for the string "TODO"

Comment: Nice idea. I'm using the Vim-plugin **Vrapper**, so I made a mapping to navigate to the next TODO. Thanks for pointing out the right path!